# mysql settings - using the available resources

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, performance, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning

I've got a lot of processing work I need to run on a mysql server.

I've installed mysql 5.1.45-community on a Win 2008 64bit.

Its running on a Xeon, 3ghz 6 processors with 8 gig ram.

It doesn't seem to matter what queries I run (or the number I run at the same time), when I look in task manager, I'll see one processor is out at 100%.  The other 5 are idol.  Memory is static at 1.54 gig.

When I installed mysql, I used the wizard and selected the default "server" (not workstation) option.

I feel like I should be getting more bang for my buck.  Is there something else I should be monitoring or something I should change to use the other system resources???

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of MySQL? The 32-bit one can't use more than just under 2Gb of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to learn how to tune MySQL's my.cnf` file. The default settings, and even many of the "sample" settings file are very very conservative. A machine with 8Gb is way beyond what those files are aiming at.

The settings you will want to look at are:

- read_buffer_size
- key_buffer
- thread_cache_size
- table_cache
- myisam_sort_buffer
- read_buffer
- read_rnd_buffer
- innodb_buffer_pool_size

There may be others. Some of them you may want to increase at least tenfold.

Some links to help you understand these settings:

- [MySQL system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html)
- [MySQL memory use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-use.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the process list on MySQL (`show full processlist;`) and the process list in Windows to verify that it is MySQL? (Task Manager)

Comment: Yes they match, it's a dedicated box